# push my project to github

Tags: github, push

I followed these steps: https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys

now, I want to create a folder in my github account, is called: "TODO_LIST", and push my project into this folder.

what I should do? I'm located in the folder I want to add.

should I need to do something like the next following?

```
$ git init
$ git add .
$ git commit -m 'first import'
$ git remote add origin git@github.com:alonshmiel/TODO_LIST.git
$ git push origin master
```

p.s, I have two SSH keys in my account because I push from two computers.

Comment: You don't need different SSH keys for different computers: just copy one of them to the other computer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is explained in the [Create a Repo](https://help.github.com/articles/create-a-repo) help page:

> Every time you make a commit with Git, it is stored in a repository (a.k.a. "repo"). To put your project up on GitHub, you'll need to have a GitHub repository for it to live in.
>
> [...]
>
> Click New Repository.
>
> Fill out the information on this page. When you're done, click "Create Repository."
>
> [...]
>
> ```
> git init
> # Sets up the necessary Git files
>
> git add README
> # Stages your README file, adding it to the list of files to be committed
> git commit -m 'first commit'
> # Commits your files, adding the message "first commit"
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> ```
> git remote add origin https://github.com/username/Hello-World.git
> # Creates a remote named "origin" pointing at your GitHub repo
> git push origin master
> # Sends your commits in the "master" branch to GitHub
> ```